# how to show the wind direction in degrees in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, weather, weather-api

I am building a weather app that shows the weather condition of each city using a weather IPA. 
I am trying to display the wind direction in degrees but I could only display in a textual description ex: Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly.. 
I want to display the wind in degrees as well.

How to show the wind direction in a degree (e.g 90°) in javascript (including the use of the small circle degree symbol after the number)?

Because I am working with data files I can't make the code work outside of the text editor if you would like to see the full code.

I could only share a part of the code which is the main thing. But don't worry, the part I couldn't share are the data files of the cities -- `please select` -- for each country --`select a country`. --

In this code, I am displaying the wind direction as a textual description, how to display in degrees as well?

```js
function text(d) {
        let directions = ['Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly', 'South Easterly', 'Southerly', 'South Westerly', 'Westerly', 'North Westerly'];

        d += 22.5;

        if (d < 0)
            d = 360 - Math.abs(d) % 360;
        else
            d = d % 360;

        let w = parseInt(d / 45);
        return `${directions[w]}`;
    }
```

```js
function getData(selectedCounty) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=' + selectedCounty + '&appid=e4761ea183f1b15b7c6af8e63724a863',
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response) {
         
             //display the chosen city and date from the requested data
             $('#cityName').empty().append('Weather for ' + response.name + ' on ' + toDD_MM_YY_format(response.dt));
             //display the city name div after the user choose country and city

             $('#weatherInfo').empty().append(
                 'Weather Conditions: ' + response.weather[0].main + '</br>' +
                 'Temperature :' + toCelsius(response.main.temp) + '</br>' +
                 'Wind Speed :' + toMilesPerHour(response.wind.speed) + '</br>' +
                 'Wind Direction: ' + text(response.wind.deg));
             displayWeatherIcon(response.weather[0].icon);
         },
         error: function() {
             $('#errorInfo').show().html('<p> An error has occurred, Please try again later</p>');
             $('#weatherInfo').empty();
         }
     });
 }

 //convert temperature in kelvin to Celsius.
 function toCelsius(kelvin) {
     var tempInCelsius = Math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
     return tempInCelsius + '°C';
 }

 //converts speed in knots to miles per hour(mph)
 function toMilesPerHour(knots) {
     var speedInMilesPerHour = Math.round(knots * 1.15077945); //1 Knot = 1.15077945 mph
     return speedInMilesPerHour + ' mph';
 }

 //converts UNIX time stamp in to readable format
 function toDD_MM_YY_format(unixTimeStamp) {
     var d = new Date(unixTimeStamp * 1000);
     var month = (d.getMonth()) + 1; //unix time stamp month starts from 0.
     var formattedDate = d.getDate() + "-" + month + "-" + d.getFullYear();
     return formattedDate;
 }
//convert the wind direction from degree to textual description.
function text(d) {
        let directions = ['Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly', 'South Easterly', 'Southerly', 'South Westerly', 'Westerly', 'North Westerly'];

        d += 22.5;

        if (d < 0)
            d = 360 - Math.abs(d) % 360;
        else
            d = d % 360;

        let w = parseInt(d / 45);
        return `${directions[w]}`;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>UK Weather Application</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="apiweather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UK Weather Data</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
        <h4>Current Weather Data</h4>
        <select id="countries">
            <option selected>Select a Country</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        </select>
        <select id="counties">
            <option selected>&lt;&lt;Please Select</option>
        </select>
       
        
        <div id="cityName"></div>
        <div id="weatherInfo"></div>
        <div id="errorInfo" hidden></div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope I explained well, please don't hesitate to ask me questions.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
let WIND_DIRECTION;
    function getWindDirection(d){
        switch (true) {
            case 0 :
            case 360:
                WIND_DIRECTION = "N";
            break;
            case 90 :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "E";
            break;
            case 180 :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "S";
            break;
            case 270 :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "W";
            break;
            case (d>0 && d<90) :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "NE";
            break;
            case (d>90 && d<180) :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "SE";
            break;
            case (d>180 && d<270) :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "SW";
            break;
            case (d>270 && d<360) :
                WIND_DIRECTION = "NW";
            break;
            default:
                WIND_DIRECTION = "-";
                break;
        }

        return WIND_DIRECTION;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: It is **not recommended** to post code-only answers, consider to also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using weather API im not really sure but maybe you could try using something like this in your `text() function`

```js
const windDegree = String.fromCharCode(0xfeff00b0);
deg = 90;

console.log(`${deg}${windDegree} = ${text(deg)}`);
```